# Alternative way of finding the Distribution of $Y_{3} = (X_{1}X_{2}X_{3})^{1/3}$

Tags: probability, self-study

Suppose that $X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3}$ are i.i.d from $p_{x}$. Determine the distribution of $Y_{3} = (X_{1}X_{2}X_{3})^{1/3}$.

$p_{X}(x) = \begin{cases}
1/2 & \text{if } x = 1,\newline
1/4 & \text{if } x = 2,\newline
1/4 & \text{if } x = 3,\newline
0 & \text{otherwise}.\newline
\end{cases}$

I can solve this problem by multiplying all the different combinations of values of x and finding the corresponding probability of Y. But there will be a lot of combinations and I feel like there has to be a better way of solving this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi! Can you show us what have you achieved so far? We are happy to help you but we can't solve homeworks for you...

Comment: @utobi..I am able to solve this problem using the tedious way of multiplying all the x values, calculating the y value and then calculating the probability. But this is a very long way of solving this problem and I feel like there has to be a better way of solving this. Thank you!

Comment: great! Add this context in the post, otherwise, it's likely that your post will be closed; take a look at the [tour](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how to ask good questions, i.e. questions that don't get downvoted or closed.

Comment: I don't see any other solution than counting all 27 cases; a tree diagram may be helpful.

Comment: Taking the logarithm transforms this into a sum of independent random variables, which means that the resulting distribution is the convolution of the individual distributions. This does not simplify anything for discrete r.v.'s, though, especially as the possible values are no longer integers.

Comment: @cdalitz I think the probability generating function for $\log((X_1X_2 X_3)^{1/3})$ might be $(\frac12 x^{\log(1)/3} + \frac14 x^{\log(2)/3} + \frac14 x^{\log(3)/3})^3$  though you will still have $10$ terms so may not be faster

Comment: @utobi since $1,2,3$ are coprime, there may be a way of reducing $3^3=27$ to ${3+3-1 \choose 3}=10$ but it may not be worth the complication

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method I can think of in this case exploits the symmetry (equal probabilities of 2 and 3) to evaluate the distribution of $$\log Y = \left(\log X_1 + \log X_2 +\log X_3\right)/3$$ by expanding the generating function of the common distribution $f(t) = 1/2 + \left(t^{\log 2} + t^{\log 3}\right)/4.$  Writing $a$ and $b$ for the two logarithms and expanding *via* the multinomial theorem we obtain the expansion

$$f_{3\log Y}(t) = (3f(t))^3 = \frac{1}{8} \sum_{i+j+k=3} \binom{3}{i;j;k} 2^{-j-k}\, t^{ja + kb} = \frac{6}{8} \sum_{i=0}^3 \frac{1}{i! 2^{3-i}}\sum_{j+k=i}\frac{t^ja+kb}{j!k!}.$$

The inner sum is symmetric in $(j,k),$ so that we only need to inspect the values for the cases $(j,k) = (0,0); (1,0); (2,0), (1,1);$ and $(3,0), (2,1).$

It's convenient to use the computer for this.  For instance, Wolfram Alpha will display the coefficients by evaluating [Expand[(1/2 + (t^a+t^b)/4)^3]](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=Expand%5B%281%2F2+%2B+%28t%5Ea%2Bt%5Eb%29%2F4%29%5E3%5D).

> [image: Mathematica output -- similar to Alpha output]

This tells us, for instance, that the chance $3\log Y = 2\log 2 + \log 3$ equals the chance $3\log Y = 2\log 3 + \log 2$ and each of these chances is the coefficient of $t^{2a+b},$ equal to $3/64.$  Equivalently, this is the chance $Y^3 = \exp(2\log 2 + \log 3) = 2^2(3) = 12$ and it's the chance $Y^3 = \exp(2\log 3 + \log 2)=18.$